# Impersonation to get user HKEY_CURRENT_USER does not work?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to Impersonate an administrator account from a LocalSystem Service in order to get data from administrators HKEY CURRENT USER registry - in order to impersonate I am using the codeproject code found at the following site written by Uwe Keim: [Impersonator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx?fid=171054&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=1#xx0xx)

My  source code is as follows:

```
using (new Impersonator("user", ".", "pass"))
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\CompanyName");
    string sValue = rk.GetValue("Value", "").ToString();
    rk2.Close();
}
```

My expectation was that sValue would be from the user/pass account (as I am impersonating it) but oddly enough it is still the sValue from the LocalSystem account where my service is runnning ...

Any clues on what I am doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread but I recently came across the same issue (albeit from a C++ Windows service) and thought I'd share my findings, because many forums have asked the same question and none have left a satisfactory answer.

Basically, I've found two ways to approach this, though this is an answer more for C applications rather than .NET (I haven't tested with pinvoke but it may work).

Solution 1:
Instead of using RegOpenKey, use [RegOpenCurrentUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the key handle. Apparently, the reason RegOpenKey doesn't get the impersonated user's key is because HKEY_CURRENT_USER is *cached* in the running thread.

Solution 2:
[RegDisablePredefinedCache()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724854%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This *disables* the cache mentioned above and lets subsequent calls to HKEY_CURRENT_USER be of the actual impersonated user. This is the solution I went with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Everything I've read on the subject seems to indicate that impersonation should get you access to the HKEY_CurrentUser for the impersonated account. However, it could be a quirk in the .NET Registry implementation.

This is just a hunch, and an untested one at that, but have you considered using Registry.Users instead of Registry.CurrentUser?

You'll need to [find the SID](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/getusersid.aspx) for the Administrator account, but you should be able to deduce that using Regedit

Comment: Not an option - this is a test to ensure that if I use RegEdit to merge a .reg file that goes to HKEY_CURRENT_USER it updates the Admin Accounts registry and not the LocalSystem account.

Comment: So why exactly does that exclude this as a possibility? HKEY_CURRENT_USER is essentially just a link to the HKEY_USERS subkey for the logged in user.

Comment: Assume I have a file.REG file which changes some in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Something\Value=Data". If I do regedit file.REG I need it to affect the admin accounts HKCU and not the LocalSystem (Service).

Finding the Registry.Users and SID won't help ...
See what I mean?

Comment: I'm severely confused. By your original post detail I was assuming you wanted to READ the value of a registry key for a specific user (in this case the administrator user). the Registry.Users call is just a different way to do the same thing and might help you work around the quirk you are seeing. HOWEVER, I think Justin is on to something with his modified answer. Try that first.

Answer (score 1):

By default the HKEY_CURRENT_USER handle is cached on a process wide basis. So when you impersonate a user and then access the current user hive you will be accessing the hive of the user that started the process not the user being impersonated. This is true for all Win32 processes not just .Net. If you wish to disable this caching so that all current user calls go to the correct user hive under HKEY_USERS then you must call [RegDisablePredefinedCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdisablepredefinedcache) via [pInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke).

Be warned that if the user being impersonated has not had their profile loaded then any CurrentUser requests will be forwarded to the .DEFAULT user. So you may also need to call LoadUserProfile.

Disabling the handle caching will also cause a slight slowdown in all CurrentUser requests.

Comment: Having trouble with the syntax here.
        [DllImport("win32.dll")]
        private static extern int RegDisablePredefinedCache(); - results in "specified module could not be found."

Comment: This compiles and runs, but I still have the issue.
        [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
        private static extern int RegDisablePredefinedCache();

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're going to find that you're out of luck. It can't be done.

If applications were able to impersonate an Administrator account and write values to the Registry in Windows, it would present a huge security hole. My guess is that the `Registry.CurrentUser` property will ALWAYS reference the user running your application...whether or not you try impersonation or not.

**EDIT**

Turns out that I didn't read the implementation details of the Impersonator code you were using. Your problem could be something completely different.

Does your code refer to the `Registry` static class prior to your impersonation code being run? If so, that would be the problem. If you look at the `Registry.CurrentUser` property in Reflector, you'll see that it is set by the static constructor of the `Registry` object. Static constructors get called when the static object is first referenced.

In your case, if you're referencing the `Registry` object (whether it involves `CurrentUser` or not) the static constructor is being called which is setting `CurrentUser` to your original user...not the Impersonated account.

Comment: I think you may be mistaken. Impersonation code actually logs in as the provided user and requires full login credentials to do so. There is no security hole here just because you are logging in using code instead of a login prompt.

Comment: The Impersonator is a LocalSystem Service which has as-much right as administrator... But if this is ok then why is it not working (any clues?)

Comment: Is the impersonator class compiled into a separate assembly? If so, have you tried pulling it into the same module as your test code to see if it behaves any differently?

Comment: Impersonator class was added into the same assembly (same exe), I just added a file with the class into my namespace and go ...

I know it works (kind of) because if I supply incorrect user/pass it throws the correct exception (wrong username/password).

Comment: Updated answer with a completely different answer. Turns out Reflector might be your friend in this case...but, as always, I could be wrong.

Comment: Good call - I was using it also prior to impersonation - however the change didn't make any difference... Now I am testing with XP and unlike with 2k previously I can nolonger access HKCU of the LocalSystem Service (exception) but HKLM works fine..